# Swiper Slider not working inside Bootstrap Tab Panel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, phonegap-plugins, swiper.js

I'm using bootstrap tab & [swiper slider](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/),I have multiples tab, in all tabs have image slider. The swiper slider is working fine except pagination in first tab but another tab, both are not working.

Basically i am doing phone-gap project. In this project requirement is that image slider into tab pane.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#Apparel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Apparel
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Electronic" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Electronic
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Furniture" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Furniture
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Mobile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Mobile
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Apparel">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Apparel Image 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Apparel Image 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Apparel Image 3</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Electronic">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Electronic Image 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Electronic Image 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Electronic Image 3</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Furniture">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Furniture Image 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Furniture Image 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Furniture Image 3</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Mobile">
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Mobile Phone Image 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Mobile Phone Image 2</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Mobile Phone Image 3</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    autoplay: 2500,
});
```

Here is my Example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/r30j0mje/6/)

Please help me....

Comment: Swiper has some known issues when using multiple instances on the same page. You can see the threads in [nolimits4web github page](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) and try the suggested solutions from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/830) and [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/273)

Comment: is there any slider or js plugins that i used in tab panel?

Answer (score 22):

Add the below code with the swiper initialisation

```
observer: true,
observeParents: true,
```

Comment: Hello, doesn't work for me. I am putting this to my code: $(document).ready(function() {
        const imageCarousel = jQuery ( '.swiper-container' );
        swiperInstance = imageCarousel.data( 'swiper' );
        swiperInstance.params.observer = true;
        swiperInstance.params.observeParents = true;

        swiperInstance.update();
}); but doesn't work. Cannot read property params of undefined... 

But while I am writting this code to console, it works :(

Comment: "observer: Set to true to enable Mutation Observer on Swiper and its elements. In this case Swiper will be updated (reinitialized) each time if you change its style (like hide/show) or modify its child elements (like adding/removing slides)

------
observeParents: Set to true if you also need to watch Mutations for Swiper parent elements"
source: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same problem. Add a class-name to the ul-tag. 
Swiper must be reinitialized:

```
$(".class-name li").on("click",function(){ 
   reinitializeSwiper(swiper);
});

function reinitializeSwiper(swiper) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        swiper.update();       
    }, 400);
}
```

Comment: The '.class-name' in the 1st line is a class of what? Of tabs?

Answer (score 1):

you must create a simple listener for the shown.bs.tab event and then use update() method.

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var paneTarget = $(e.target).attr('href');
  var $thePane = $('.tab-pane' + paneTarget);
  var paneIndex = $thePane.index();
  if ($thePane.find('.swiper-container').length > 0 && 0 === $thePane.find('.swiper-slide-active').length) {
    mySwiper[paneIndex].update();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5.2.3, I will manage to do by following code:

```
$('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 30,
     autoplay: {
            delay: 2500,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
          },
          pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            clickable: true,
          },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          },
  });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

My Swiper 3.4.2

I will add a problem and a solution to the problem:

When switching between tabs, **Autorun stops working**!

```
observer: true,
observeParents: true,
```

Despite the fact that we have initialized Swiper.

**Solution to the problem:**

```
$("li[role='presentation']").children("a").on("click",function () {
    var gallerySwiper = $('.swiper-container');
    $.each(gallerySwiper, function( index, value ) {
      value.swiper.stopAutoplay();
      value.swiper.startAutoplay();
    });
});
```

But for this code to work without errors, you need to exclude (**loop: true**)

**loop: true,** // this hinder autoplay

My more detailed comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665700/15039618

Look at the **picture**!

[image]