# Stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

How to stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave? I have tried `.stopAutoplay()` and `.startAutoplay()` function but not worked for me.

thank you here is code. and i face console error

> Uncaught TypeError: swiper .startAutoplay is not a function

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    loop: true,
    effect: 'slide',
    longSwipes: true,
    autoplay:2000,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction:true,
});


$(".swiper-container").mouseenter(function(){
    swiper.stopAutoplay();
});

$(".swiper-container").mouseleave(function(){
    swiper.startAutoplay();
});
```

Comment: there is no option like `autoplayDisableOnInteraction` but `disableOnInteraction` .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the option `disableOnInteraction: true` rather than binding the events yourself see here for [documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#autoplay).

Optionally you can use the following for autoplay start stop

- `swiper.autoplay.start();`
- `swiper.autoplay.stop();`

**Edit**

Your mistake is how you are getting the instance for swiper. see below for demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100,
    autoplay: true,
    disableOnInteraction: true,
  });
  var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper

  $(".swiper-container").mouseenter(function() {
    mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
    console.log('slider stopped');
  });

  $(".swiper-container").mouseleave(function() {
    mySwiper.autoplay.start();
    console.log('slider started again');
  });
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do not work for me. face console error Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined

Comment: add console.log(swiper) just before you call start stop what does it print in console

Comment: I add this console.log('Enter');
This work fine but see undefined method 'stop' and 'start'

Comment: just updated my answer and added the code snippet look closely how you have to get the instance for the swiper, that was your mistake @MahmudulHasanSohag. hope it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks @ Muhammad Omer Aslam , It's work for me
I face another problem. I use wordpress  post query and for that many swiper-container are print.
First container's autoplay stop when i mouse hover any swiper container. But i want it each specific container.
how I can i solve it

Comment: can you create another post for this problem with your existing code and tag me there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158776/discussion-between-mahmudul-hasan-sohag-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: sorry i am out currently cant chat thats y asked you to add another post and tag me ,will see when i come back home

Comment: am getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoplay' of undefined

Comment: There isnt any error in the example snippet above. if you are talking about your code please add your question by creating a post @user264675

Answer (score 18):

According to the documentation of swiper.js version 8
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay

```
autoplay: {
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
},
```

Comment: that works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
....
...
....
});

$(".swiper-container").hover(function() {
    (this).swiper.autoplay.stop();
}, function() {
    (this).swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

generic solution for multiple sliders on same page.

Comment: This is the best, most simple and straightforward answer in my opinion. Thanks

Comment: But, I just realized, it doesn't pause my thumbnails below the main slider.

Comment: @JeremyCaris Probably because they are not the children of the .swiper-container element.

Answer (score 5):

For several instances the only code works is the following:

```js
$(".swiper-container").each(function(elem, target){
    var swp = target.swiper;
    $(this).hover(function() {
        swp.autoplay.stop();
    }, function() {
        swp.autoplay.start();
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer pauses the main slider and thumbnails in my situation. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Mark, this is the best solution. As the Elementor has added improved asset loading, it only works inside `$(window).on('load', function () {`.
Reference: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/13268

Answer (score 3):

New parameter has been added to Swiper v6.6.0 (pauseOnMouseEnter), so there is no need for a workaround from now:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay

Comment: This should be the proper way from now on. Option named `pauseOnMouseEnter` has been added under `Autoplay` property.

Answer (score 2):

In vuejs (with [`vue-awesome-swiper`](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper)), I had to wrap the `swiper` component with a `div` and then added the event listeners to the div.

```
<v-flex @mouseenter="$refs.swiperRef.swiper.autoplay.stop()"
        @mouseleave="$refs.swiperRef.swiper.autoplay.start()">
    <swiper :options="swiperOptions"
            ref="swiperRef">
        <swiper-slide v-for="(product, index) in products"
                      :key="index">
            <!-- -->
        </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
</v-flex>
```

Putting the event listeners on the component directly did not work

Answer (score 1):

For Vue 3 with vue components from `swiper/vue`:

```
<template>
  <swiper
      :slides-per-view="1"
      @swiper="onSwiper"
      @mouseenter="() => this.swiper.autoplay.stop()"
      @mouseleave="() => this.swiper.autoplay.start()"
  >
    <template v-for="pic in pictures">
      <swiper-slide>
        <figure>
          <div v-html="pic.html"></div>
          <figcaption>{{ pic.title }}</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </swiper-slide>
    </template>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script>
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';

export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      swiper: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSwiper(swiper) {
      this.swiper = swiper;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: :autoplay="{
        delay: 2000,
        disableOnInteraction: true,
        pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
      }"
 pauseOnMouseEnter: true, If you use this simply stop

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using vuejs directive for swipper : [vue-awesome-swiper](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper)

```
<div class="swiper-container" v-swiper:mySwiper="swiperOptions" @mouseenter="stopSwip($event)" @mouseleave="startSwip($event)">
    ....
</div>


<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    stopSwip(event) {
        event.target.swiper.autoplay.stop();
    },
    startSwip(event) {
        event.target.swiper.autoplay.start();
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me like this:

***three conditions***

1. My Swiper 3.4.2
2. Slider in tabs (5pcs)
3. Scroll arrows are inside the slider

   ```
   // showed initialization as an example, in my case, to initialize each of the 5 sliders, such code in each tab.
   var swiper = new Swiper('#tab-<?php echo $count; ?> .swiper-container', {
      mode: 'horizontal',
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      nextButton: '#five_modules_tabs #tab-<?php echo $count; ?> .swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '#five_modules_tabs #tab-<?php echo $count; ?> .swiper-button-prev',
      breakpoints: {
         // when window width is <= 410px
         410: {
           slidesPerView: 1.1,
           spaceBetween: 4
         },
         // when window width is <= 430px
         430: {
            slidesPerView: 1.11,
            spaceBetween: 4
         },
         // when window width is <= 460px
         460: {
            slidesPerView: 1.12,
            spaceBetween: 4,
            nextButton: '',
            prevButton: '',
         },
         // when window width is <= 640px
         640: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 4
         },
         // when window width is <= 767px
         767: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 4
         },
         // when window width is <= 991px
         991: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 12
         },
         // when window width is <= 1199px
         1199: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 15
         }
      },
      pagination: '#five_modules_tabs #tab-<?php echo $count; ?> .swiper-pagination',
      paginationClickable: true,
      autoplay: 1000,
      autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false, // Does not work
      //loop: true, //this hinder autoplay
      observer: true,
      observeParents: true,
      observeSlideChildren: true
   });
   ```

But for this code `.on("click")` to **work without errors**, you need to exclude  `loop: true`

```js
// restart autoplay after switching tabs
$("#five_modules_tabs .nav-tabs li").on("click", function(e) {
  var gallerySwiper = $('#five_modules_tabs .swiper-container');
  $.each(gallerySwiper, function( index, value ) {
    value.swiper.stopAutoplay();
    value.swiper.startAutoplay();
  });
});
```

`loop: true,` - This hinder autoplay

Instead of a non-working `autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,` stops the slider on hover.
You need to stop when hovering on any of these blocks (`.swiper-container, .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next, .swiper-pagination`) === ('#five_modules_tabs .swiper-container')

All blocks are inside `.swiper-viewport`

```js
$('#five_modules_tabs .swiper-container').each(function(index, value) {
  $('#five_modules_tabs .swiper-viewport').hover(function() {
    value.swiper.stopAutoplay();
  }, function() {
    value.swiper.startAutoplay();
  });
});
```

**Look at the picture!**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the web Component of swiper(>9.0):

```
<swiper-container autoplay-deplay=2000 
       autoplay-disable-on-interaction="false" autoplay-pause-on-mouse-enter="true">
       <swiper-slide class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</swiper-slide>
       <swiper-slide class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</swiper-slide>
       <swiper-slide class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

can also use:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
 autoplay: {
   delay: 2000,
   disableOnInteraction: false,
   pauseOnMouseEnter: true
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `autoplay` property, you can add the following parameter set to `true`:

```
new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
  },
}
```

[Reference from the official documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-pauseOnMouseEnter)