# Swiper js in Raect how to stop autoplay onMouseEnter and start it onMouseLeave

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, autoplay

I am trying to learn swiper.js in react by building a simple image slider with autoplay and I don't know how to
stop autoplay onMouseEnter and start it onMouseLeave.
I tried onMouseLeave={Swiper.autoplay.stop} and it didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './HeroSlider.module.css';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'; // swiper.min.css
import image1 from '../../Images/image1.png';
import image2 from '../../Images/image2.png';
import image3 from '../../../Images/image3.png';

SwiperCore.use([ Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay ]);

const HeroSlider = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper 
      className={ classes.MainSlider }
      autoplay={{ delay: 5000, disableOnInteraction: false, reverseDirection: true, waitForTransition: true }}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      navigation
      onMouseEnter={}
      onMouseLeave={}
    >
      <SwiperSlide className="full-w-h-container" tag="li" style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <img className={ `full-w-h-container ${ classes.ImgBg }` } src={image1} alt="image1" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide className="full-w-h-container" tag="li" style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <img className={ `full-w-h-container ${ classes.ImgBg }` } src={image2} alt="image2" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide className="full-w-h-container" tag="li" style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        <img className={ `full-w-h-container ${ classes.ImgBg }` } src={image3} alt="image3" />
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  )
}
export default HeroSlider;
```

Edit:

I tried something like
onMouseEnter={() => Swiper.autoplay.stop()}
onMouseLeave={() => Swiper.autoplay.start()}
but It doesn't work strangely though if I use something like:
onClick={() => Swiper.autoplay.stop()}
It works...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238245/stop-swiper-slide-autoplay-on-mouse-enter-and-start-autoplay-on-mouse-leave

Comment: I tried something like
      onMouseEnter={() => Swiper.autoplay.stop()}
      onMouseLeave={() => Swiper.autoplay.start()}
but It doesn't work strangely though if I use something like:
      onClick={() => Swiper.autoplay.stop()}
It works...

Answer (score 8):

At the time of writing this, it looks like Swiper for React doesn't implement `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave`, etc.

To work around this, I wrapped my Swiper component in another React component and referenced Swiper with a reference like so:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Pagination } from 'swiper'
// ...

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Pagination])

export default function Slider() {
  const swiperRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div 
      onMouseEnter={() => swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.stop()}
      onMouseLeave={() => swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.start()}
    >
      <Swiper
        ref={swiperRef}
        autoplay={{ delay: 5000 }}
        speed={1300}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        allowTouchMove={false}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      >
        {/* slides */}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Workable Solution. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `pauseOnMouseEnter: true`:

```
autoplay={{
 delay: 3000,
 disableOnInteraction: false,
 pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
}}
```

Comment: That's not implemented on Swiper React atm it seems.