# Swiper React how to stop and start autoplay on hover with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I am using [Swiper js](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) for my carousel and React and Typescript.

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448980/swiper-js-in-raect-how-to-stop-autoplay-onmouseenter-and-start-it-onmouseleave), I am trying to `stop()` and `start()` autoplay on hover. I need this approach because I have to create some states when hovering the Swiper container.

**1)** I get a typescript error the `ref` property on my `<Swiper ref={swiperRef}>` component:

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Swiper &
> { children?

**2)** how do I get acces to swiper, so I can use `swiper.autoplay.stop();` inside my `handleMouseEnter` function? So I can use like:

```
const handleMouseEnter = () => {
  swiper.autoplay.stop();
 };
```

or like:

```
const handleMouseEnter = () => {
 swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.stop();
};
```

This is [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-hover-typescript-d1lng) what I have so far.

How do I get this to work using Typescript?

Answer (score 5):

you can store your swiper when it is initialized in a ref then use its controllerEvents like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Pagination } from "swiper";

SwiperCore.use([Pagination, Autoplay]);

export default function SwiperComponent() {
  const swiperRef = React.useRef<SwiperCore>();
  const onInit = (Swiper: SwiperCore): void => {
    swiperRef.current = Swiper;
  };
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    if (swiperRef.current) swiperRef.current.autoplay.start();
  };
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    if (swiperRef.current) swiperRef.current.autoplay.stop();
  };

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
      <Swiper onInit={onInit}>
        <SwiperSlide></SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The requirement for `.autoplay` (which their docs do not mention) threw me. FWIW you can do `swiperRef.current?.autoplay` to save yourself the `if`.